# Is it recommended to put part-time jobs on resumes?

Tags: cv

My former employer and I have a good relationship, and they expressed that they like my work ethic. I asked them to be a reference for me, and they were willing. This and the fact I spent years at the job is the only reason I would list my part-time job, because other than that it isn't "impressive" or relevant for a resume in academia in my opinion.

Comment: What degree step are you pursuing? What types of things are you applying for?

Comment: At what stage of your academic career are you? For an application to a post-doc position I'd say "no", for a PhD position the answer would be "probably yes" (depending on what else is on your CV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say because every selection committee/PI is different. If you do not have too many of these, or you worked there for a longer period of time, I think it is a good idea to list them, especially if they are willing to be a reference for you. So, in your case, I would definitely list that job.

If you do a "European" type of CV with few details about the job, the 1-2 extra lines are not that much anyways and people can ask about the job in the interview if they wish. If you do the "American" type of CV, emphasise the tasks and skills that are also relevant in academia or how they are transferable.

I also think that if you worked during your studies, your CV should show this fact, because it is much harder to perform well both at work and your studies.

Depending on the job, your skills might get used by the group. For example, I had a part-time job in HR, which I listed on my CV (also at post-doc level), so I am asked quite often to screen candidates and join interviews and the like. So from this perspective, if you disliked the job, you may want to hide it.